# (node:2256) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make a whatapp bot brainly nodejs. And I want to add an argument. my code is like this:

```
                case 'brainly':
                const args = process.argv
                    brainly(args).then(res => {
                        for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++){
                        var jawab = res[i].jawaban
                        client.sendText(from, jawab[0].text)
                        }
                    })
                break
```

But, when I run it shows an error like this:

> (node:7960) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

how to fix this? Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `.catch()` like the error message suggests?

Answer (score 2):

This means that somewhere in an asynchronous context, most likely inside of the promise created by calling `brainly(args)`, an error occurred, and it wasn't caught and dealt with.

To get started with asynchronous Javascript, I recommend finding some [articles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) about Javascript Promises and Async Functions (that implicitly generate promises, and allow for the `await` syntax).

There's no real easy way to explain. Javascript is a single-threaded language, but it offers great concurrency through the use of callbacks, promises and the async/await syntax (they all sort of originate from callbacks). Anything that does not happen instantaneously, such as network/disk operations, is *asynchronous* and must be handled in an appropriate manner. This can be confusing for newcomers as it breaks up the linear *asyncronous* flow of execution.

Promises are objects that can be created that will either *resolve* or *reject* in the future. By calling `.then` on the promise, you are giving it a *callback function* that will be called with the resolved value, when it eventually arrives. You should also add a `.catch(err => { ... })` handler to the end to deal with errors, which is probably being thrown for some reason as a result of your passed arguments.